# Array list not being searched properly

Tags: java, arrays, contains

I am having a hard time to get this to work. The isLoop() method gets called every time something is added to the array to make sure there are no duplicates. When there is a duplicate, it should return true. But it isn't.

```
isLoop(){
    if(!Arrays.asList(SQUARES).contains(sq)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something fundamental about arrays? I am fairly new to Java, so it is probably the case! :D

**EDIT**

I have been asked to show how the objects were instansiated, so I have posted the whole class here:

```
class Happy {
static int SQUARES[] = new int[10000];
static int sq;

public static boolean isHappy(int num){
    int s = 0;
    int n = num;

    int i=0;

    for(sq = num; (!isLoop()) && (sq > 1);){
        sq = addSquaresOfDigits(sq);
        SQUARES[i] = sq;
        i++;

    }

    if(isLoop()){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

static int addSquaresOfDigits(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    int tmp;
    while(number > 0) {
        tmp = number % 10;
        result += tmp * tmp;
        number /= 10;
    }
return result;
}

static boolean isLoop(){
    if(!Arrays.asList(SQUARES).contains(sq)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The method isHappy() will test the number given it to see whether it is a [happy number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) or not.

Comment: What does SQUARES contain? Is it a type you've defined? It could be you have a buggy implementation of `equals()`.

Comment: what is sq? what was originally added to the array? does sq's class have override the equals() method?

Comment: sq is the current value of the item being added to the array. It does not override the equals() method

Comment: Lewis what type of object is sq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you define `equals()` and `hashCode()` on the `sq` class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for details on that.

If the `sq` instance doesn't implement `equals()` then it will use the default implementation in `Object` which is to check if the two objects are the same instance.

Comment: sq must be an instance of a class, or the snippet you've added wouldn't compile.  Can you update the question to show how you've instantiated `sq`?

Answer (score 0):

For a start you can simplify your code to the following:

```
isLoop(){
    return Arrays.asList(SQUARES).contains(sq);
}
```

Despite what you've said elsewhere, `SQUARES` must be an array and `sq` must be an object instance of a Class or your code wouldn't compile.

The `equals()` method of `sq` will have to return true when called on one of the objects in `SQUARES` for `isLoop()` to return true.

Comment: Thanks... I am new to Java, so the little details slip by me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to some Set implementation (e.g. `HashSet` class) to search if collections does or does not contain particular element. It's much faster then looping over the list. A

As mentioned aboce, remember about `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You state in a comment you haven't overriden `equals()` or `hashCode()`, this will be your issue as by default (and by design) Java doesn't know if two objects are meaningfully equal (since this will differ depending on the class!)

Have a look [here](http://bytes.com/topic/java/insights/723476-overriding-equals-hashcode-methods) for a good guide on the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods and how to implement them properly. Alternatively, if you're feeling lazy, many IDEs will implement them for you based on a number of chosen fields. I'd only recommend this approach when you know how they work however!

As an aside, it seems you're using a list here when a HashSet would be a much better choice - by design it doesn't contain duplicates and is very fast at detecting them (it doesn't need to go through the entire list to check them as you're doing here.)

Comment: I just edited my original question to include the full class that the isLoop() method sits in. All other begginner java mistakes aside, how would I use a Hash Set? Like this?

`Set SQUARES = new HashSet();`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting SQUARES to list , i think that to use `contains` method ,you are using this conversion.

For example consider ,if you want to get the index of an value i.e. **static int  sq = 9;**

```
Arrays.binarySearch(SQUARES,sq);  // returns the index at which the value 9 is present
```